# Calculate $\displaystyle \iiint_A(xy+z+1)dxdydz$, where $A$ is the region bounded by the cones $z=2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=6-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Calculate $\displaystyle \iiint_A(xy+z+1)dxdydz$, where $A$ is the region bounded by the cones $z=2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z=6-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

I observed that the intersection of the cones is the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ that is situated in the plane $z=4$. Hence, I can write that $$\iiint_A(xy+z+1)dxdydz=\iint_{x^2+y^2\le 4}\left(\int_{2+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{6-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(xy+z+1)dz\right)dxdy$$
and now after I pass to polar coordinates the problem is solved (there are some tedious calculations). Is this correct? Did I reduce the triple integral to a double integral correctly?

Comment: Yes it is correct. The only thing to notice is that the integral of $xy$ over the region is going to be zero due to symmetry and $xy$ being positive in two quadrants and negative in two. So you can simplify the integrand to $(z+1)$

Comment: @MathLover Thank you! I didn't notice that, this simplifies the computations a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The upside and downside cones meet at $z=4$ and in cylinder coordinates
$x=r \cos\phi$, $y=r\sin\phi$ with Jacobian $r$

$$
V=\int_{2}^6 dz \int_0 rdr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi (xy+z+1)
$$
$$
=
\int_{2}^4 dz \int_0^{z-2} rdr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi (r^2\sin\phi\cos\phi+z+1)
+\int_4^6 dz \int_0^{6-z} rdr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi (r^2\sin\phi\cos\phi+z+1)
$$
$$
=
2\pi\int_{2}^4 dz \int_0^{z-2} rdr (z+1)
+2\pi \int_4^6 dz \int_0^{6-z} rdr (z+1)
$$
$$
=
2\pi\int_{2}^4 dz \frac{(z-2)^2}{2} (z+1)
+2\pi \int_4^6 dz \frac{(6-z)^2}{2}  (z+1)
$$
$$
=
2\pi\times 6
+2\pi \times \frac{22}{3} =\frac{80}{3}\pi.
$$